# trigger before insert on t1 using a field from t2

Tags: mysql, triggers, inner-join

I have **goods_input** and **goods_input_price** tables and want to calculate a total amount when inserting a new row in **goods_input**.
Trigger is the following:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `gym`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `total`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
    TRIGGER `total` BEFORE INSERT ON `goods_input` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

       SET new.goods_input_total_amount=new.goods_input_quantity*goods_input_price.`price_goods_input_price` 
       WHERE goods_input.`id_goods_input_price`=goods_input_price.`id_goods_input_price`;

    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

This is the error message:

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'where
>   goods_input.`id_goods_input_price`=goods_input_price.`id_goods_input_price' at line 6

Comment: Whats your question ?

Comment: I cannot create a proper inner join perhaps. I pasted the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The `set` statement does not have a `where` clause. If you want data from another table, then you need to fetch them via a `select` into variables in the trigger.

```
CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
    TRIGGER `total` BEFORE INSERT ON `goods_input` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        DECLARE input_price integer; /*use whatever datatype you have in your db for the price */
        SELECT price_goods_input_price INTO input_price FROM goods_input_price
        WHERE id_goods_input_price=NEW.id_goods_input_price LIMIT 1;
        SET new.goods_input_total_amount=new.goods_input_quantity*input_price;

    END$$
```

Comment: It is working. Thank you very much. What is actually "LIMIT 1" doing?

Comment: Making sure that the select returns a single value only.

Comment: Is it suggested to enlarge the trigger and include update clause as well?

Comment: I cannot possibly answer this question. This depends on your business requirements.

Comment: I want to have the same one for update on that table. What should I change?

Comment: If you have a follow up question, then pls adk it in its own separate question and not in a comment to an existing one. It is not nice.